# MYSQL - Correct way to get average from top 5 of 7 days?

Tags: mysql, date, average

I'm tracking number of steps/day. I want to get the average steps/day using the 5 best days out of a 7 day period. Once I get a working query for that, I'll do the same for active minutes. My end goal is going to be to get an average for the best 5 out of 7 days for a total of 16 weeks.

[Here is my sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/725298/1)

Here is the query I've got so far (encodedid is the unique ID assigned to each user):

```
SELECT AVG(activities.steps) AS AVGSteps, (SUM(activities.lightly_act_min)+SUM(activities.fairly_act_min)+SUM(activities.vact_min)) AS AVGActiveMin FROM activities, faculty WHERE  
activities.activitydate BETWEEN
DATE_ADD(faculty.startsemester, INTERVAL 0 DAY)  AND 
DATE_ADD(faculty.startsemester, INTERVAL 7 day) 
GROUP BY activities.encodedid
ORDER BY `activities`.`steps`
```

It correctly returns an average for all 7 days but I can't figure out how to return an average for the 5 best days out of that 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to basically use your existing query as a subquery so that you can select the best 5 days (I presume 5 highest days) out of 7 and then take the averages. Note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive so your end date should be the start date + 6 days, not +7).

```
SELECT AVG(a.steps) AS AVGSteps, SUM(a.lightly_act_min)+SUM(a.fairly_act_min)+SUM(a.vact_min) AS AVGActiveMin 
FROM (SELECT * FROM activities
      JOIN faculty
      WHERE activities.activitydate BETWEEN
          DATE_ADD(faculty.startsemester, INTERVAL 0 DAY)  AND 
          DATE_ADD(faculty.startsemester, INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
      ORDER BY activities.steps DESC
      LIMIT 5) a
GROUP BY a.encodedid
```

Comment: I used the query to get the best 5 of 7 days for active minutes but the output is not correct.  Here is the code I've tried:

SELECT AVG(SUMActiveMin) AS AVGActiveMin 
FROM (SELECT *, SUM(activities.lightly_act_min)+SUM(activities.fairly_act_min)+SUM(activities.vact_min) AS SUMActiveMin FROM activities 
JOIN Courses 
WHERE activities.activitydate 
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(Courses.Startsemester, INTERVAL 0 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(Courses.Startsemester, INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
ORDER BY SUMActiveMin DESC LIMIT 5 ) a 
GROUP BY a.encodedid

It's outputting the total minutes for all 7 days, not 5. Ideas?

Comment: Hi Tim, you're using GROUPing functions in the subquery which won't work and I don't think are necessary. Try changing `SUM(activities.lightly_act_min)+SUM(activities.fairly_act_min)+SUM(activities.vact_min) AS SUMActiveMin` to `activities.lightly_act_min+activities.fairly_act_min+activities.vact_min AS SUMActiveMin`

Comment: Excellent! That gave me the results I was looking for. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: No worries, glad I was able to help.